# uwp anniversary update Binary formatter

Tags: c#, arrays, serialization, uwp, binaryformatter

I cannot find **Binary Formatter** class in uwp project targeting **anniversary sdk**. The issue is I need to share a helper class with some methods which uses **Binary Formatter** between 3 projects
1. webapi ( dotner core 3 )
2. uwp main app ( 1809 sdk )
3. uwp side app ( anniversary sdk )

now the binary formatter is by default available in 1st 2 projects but in the third one it causes compile error. I am using this helper class for encryption basically.

**Code**

```
private byte[] ConvertIntoByte(object value)
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        bf.Serialize(ms, value ?? "null");
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are either missing the Reference or the using statement at top of module.  To check reference open Solution Explorer and check the Reference tab.

Comment: @jdweng "using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;" this works for other 2 projects but cnt find this using in the 3rd project which specific nuget or dll I need to add for this to work? VS suggests me to install "EcoCore" but even after installing that it cnt find this namespace

Comment: You can add the reference in the Project : Add Reference method.  You need to check the other project and see where the dll is located.  You can use the Browse tab to add the reference if it is not under the Net or Com tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> now the binary formatter is by default available in 1st 2 projects but in the third one it causes compile error.

The problem is that [`BinaryFormatter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter?view=netframework-4.8) class only [applies to](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter?view=netframework-4.8#applies-to) .Net Standard 2.0 2.1. It means that the minimum UWP support version is 16299. So please modify your side app target minimum version to 16299. Or install third-part lib such as [`EcoCore`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EcoCore).

Answer (score 1):

I had to add "EcoCore" nuget and then reload project clean and rebuild solved the issue.